# YUI Loader for YUI 3 does not load tabview

Tags: yui

I have spent hours with this issue.  I'm about ready to tear my project apart, line by line to get this figured out.  But I was wondering if anyone else had this issue:

My project works great in Firefox.  My customers use IE (classic - alot of people do...).  My boss wants me to get this done yesterday.

I can't get IE 8 or 9 (with my document in IE 7 emulation mode) to run the following, and load the TabView.  I get an error in the debugger console that telling me that it doesn't load it.  I have all the required modules for tabview loaded via  tags, so there is no dependence on an Internet connection - offline operation (again.. works great in Firefox).

```
YUI({bootstrap:false,insertBefore: 'yui3-style-overrides', filter: ''}).use('tabview','tabview-base','event-synthetic','event','event-custom','event-mouseenter','oop','yui','dom','dom-base','node','io','datasource','resize','anim','anim-easing','event-base-ie','dom-style-ie','node-focusmanager','node-event-simulate','plugin','classnamemanager','pluginhost','event-base','tabview-plugin','attribute','base','widget','widget-base-ie','arraylist','widget-parent','widget-child','event-simulate',function(Y) {

/* sand boxed code here */

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently yui (3.2 or 3.3) factored out their ie fixes into separate files in the build. This caused a nightmare for me as well. You could test it with 3.1.1 if you want to isolate your variables.

What contributed more to my insanity was that I was stupid enough to use the YUI PHP Loader, which gets worse with every YUI release because YUI is getting so many dependencies even hacked up crap like the PHP Loader cannot account for all situations.

I worked around this by manually loading all the *-ie-* files using

`<!--[if IE 7]><script type="text/javascript" src=myfile.js></script><![endif]-->`

for a month or two before I was able to come up with a smarter but larger version of PHP Loader (Which, alas, I cannot share).

To see if this is your problem, use that if ie script above for every IE specific file in the build folder. Here is a list:

```
build/dom/dom-style-ie-debug.js
build/event/event-base-ie-debug.js
build/history/history-hash-ie-debug.js
build/scrollview/scrollview-base-ie-debug.js
build/widget/widget-base-ie-debug.js
```

If I were you, I'd manually load all of those except for maybe history, which you might not need - just so you can minimize your variables.

TBH, when I had this problem and troubleshot it, I loaded *every* yui JS file. It took a while, but the bug disappeared and I was hot on the trail of finding the -ie- files issue.

Comment: Thank YOU for this answer.  I ended up doing what you've suggested above, and i feel that I'm closer.  I actually was attempting to load all the modules, but apparently, the path for TabView was mistyped!  Typo fixed - tabview loading went away... Just ended up with other issues to fix - I'm hot on the trail though...